# How to move the ownership/copy a table from one user to another?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I've been tasked with doing some tidying of our database. I'm not a DBA expert so here I am. (We don't have a DBA expert either).

We have a user `Old_User` and another user `New_User`.

`Old_User` owns a set of tables, `Table_A` and `Table_B`.
`New_User` has synonyms `t_a` and `t_b` respectively.

Can anyone give me some advice on how I should go about moving the ownership of `Table_A` and `Table_B` to `New_User`.

There are tables owned by `New_User` which have foreign keys to the tables owned by `Old_User`. I'm not sure if that complicates anything? Ideally, all referential integrity and constraints should be the same.

The goal will be to delete the `Old_User` eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the owner of a table.

You can create a new table that is owned by `NEW_USER`, copy the data from the old table to the new table, drop the foreign key constraints that reference the old table, and create new foreign key constraints that reference the new table.  But that's realistically going to require a downtime window since the tables need to be static while this copy is going on.

There are various ways to create a new table that is a copy of the old table.  Personally, I'd use your favorite PL/SQL IDE (i.e. SQL Developer, TOAD, etc.) to generate the DDL for `Old_User.Table_A` and then manually edit the DDL to create `New_User.Table_A`.  You could also do an export & import with the `FROMUSER` and `TOUSER` parameters.  Or you can use the `DBMS_METADATA` package to get the DDL

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl( 'TABLE', 'TABLE_A', 'OLD_USER' ) 
  FROM dual
```

and edit that.

Once you've created the new table, you can copy the data over

```
INSERT INTO new_user.table_a( <<list of columns>> )
  SELECT <<list of columns>>
    FROM old_user.table_a
```

Then, you'll need to go through each child table dropping the old foreign key constraint and creating the new constraint, i.e.

```
ALTER TABLE child_of_a
 DROP CONSTRAINT fk_constraint_name;

ALTER TABLE child_of_a
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (name_of_column_in_child)
      REFERENCES new_user.table_a( name_of_column_in_parent )
```

If you have enough child tables, you could potentially write a script that dynamically generates that DDL.

Once that's done, you can drop the old table and let the applications start modifying the data again.

Comment: I have a question regarding the insert into one user to another user. I am using TOAD version 9. How can log in into both user simultaneously to fire the query you suggested? Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large number of tables and a good enough blackout window, it will be simpler to do this task using Data Pump with the REMAP_SCHEMA option.

Ref.: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm